# Corr function in python, is it shows linear reliance between variables?

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

Whether the `corr()` function presents linear reliance between independent variables in Linear Regression model ?

When correlation is closly to 1 or -1 it means that there is a stron correlation between variables and when correlation is closly 0 it means that there is not correlation, nevertheless, whether correlation means linear reliance ?

Comment: Usually Pearson correlation coefficient is used when computing correlation, it measures only linear relationships between variables.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d4/Correlation_examples2.svg/1920px-Correlation_examples2.svg.png This image is very informative on what correlation coefficient can do and can't do